# Query con OR y INNER JOIN

Tags: sql

Tengo 3 tablas involucradas y la query basica que funciona y salen 14 resultados

```
SELECT * fROM agent h INNER JOIN historical_organization 
ho ON h.id = ho.agent_id and h.id in(1,2,3) 
INNER JOIN organizations o ON HO.ORGANIZATION_ID=O.ID and o.id in(1) and  
o.type='Test'
```

Esto me devuelve los agentes que tienen ese id y esa organización.
Necesito que se cumplan una de estas condiciones para que me de los agentes

```
- TENGA EL ID DEL AGENTE ENE EL IN y tengan esos id de la organizacion  => esto ya lo tengo con esa query
o
-TENGA EL ID DEL AGENTE ENE EL IN y si no tiene ninguna organizacion tipo test
```

Datos Agente:

```
1 Ivan
2 Maria
3 Carlos
4 Paco
```

Datos Organización:

```
ID  NAME       TYPE
1   Coca cola  Test
2   Pepsi      Test
3   Red bull   Bebidas
```

Datos Agent-Organization

```
ID   AGENT_ID  ORGANIZATION_ID
1     1        1
2     2        2
3     3        3
4     4        3
```

Resultado esperado

```
1 Ivan     => cumple el id de agente dentro del in(obligatorio) y cumple el ID de organizacion dentro del in 
3 Carlos   => cumple el id de agente dentro del in(obligatorio) y cumple que no tiene ninguna organizacion de tipo test
```

Comment: si usaras join, podrias hacer un left join y listo, fin del problema... porque usas el metodo antiguo de union de tablas???

Comment: creo que necesitas un UNION, pero es muy complejo entender lo que necesitas.. si no, te vas a meter en una mezcla de cosas.. porque no haces otra query que traiga la segunda parte, y despues las unis???

Comment: necesito un INNER JOIN, pensaba que mi pregunat era clara, voy a editarla, me gustaria hacerla en uan sola consulta

Comment: Agrega datos de entrada, datos de salida, la salida esperada y la que obtenes ahora.. si no estamos tirando ideas en el aire...

Comment: de paso, el titulo no tiene nada que ver con lo que planteas en la pregunta...

Comment: he añadido un ejemplo para que quede más claro

Comment: No entiendo lo de "no sé predecir cómo hacer el conteo de que si no existe ninguna organización tipo test". ¿Por qué no usar `LEFT JOIN` o `UNION`, tal como te indicaron?

Comment: supongo que lo que buscas es mas complejo.. pero asi como esta planteado, alcanzaria con poner todo tu where dentro de parentesis (salvo las clausulas de join, que no deberian estar ahi) y hacer OR (las dos otras clausulas que queres)... El problema de esto, es que va a solucionar este ejemplo, pero por algun motivo, dudo que realmente ande en tu escenario real...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quieres ver los agentes que están en organización 1 plus los agentes que no están en ninguna organización de tipo 'Test'. Para ver si un agente cumple una de las dos condiciones puedes usar `[NOT] EXISTS` o `[NOT] IN`.

Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM agent a 
WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3)
AND
(
  a.id IN (SELECT ho.agent_id
           FROM historical_organization ho
           WHERE ho.organization_id = 1)
  OR
  a.id NOT IN (SELECT ho.agent_id
               FROM historical_organization ho
               INNER JOIN organizations o ON o.id = ho.organization_id
               WHERE o.type = 'Test')
);
```

Comment: gracias, modifique lo qu necesitaba realmente pero tu consulta me sirvió para mi objetivo

Answer (score 0):

Parece que necesitarías algo como esto.

```
SELECT * 
FROM agent              h 
JOIN agent_organization ho ON h.id = ho.agent_id
JOIN organizations      o  ON o.id = ho.organization_id 
WHERE h.id IN (1, 2, 3) 
  AND (
        ( o.id IN (1) AND o.type =  'Test')
      OR NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                     FROM  agent_organization iho 
                     JOIN  organizations      io  ON io.id = iho.organization_id 
                     WHERE h.id = iho.agent_id
                     AND   io.TYPE = 'Test')
      );
```

En primer lugar, cambiamos la sintaxis obsoleta del `JOIN` para darle una mejor estructura.

Después agrupamos las condiciones que ya se cumplían y agregamos otra usando `OR` para identificar los agentes que *no existen* entre los que tienen organizaciones tipo Test.

Comment: te falto un join en la segunda parte dentro del not exists ;)

Comment: ¿Por qué lo dices? No necesitamos incluir a la tabla de agentes porque no hace falta ninguno de sus atributos para la validación.

Comment: Hola  Luis, la consulta me devuelve agentes que no estan en la consulta del In

Comment: @LuisCazares tenes razon lo lei mal... mil disculpas..

Comment: @sirdaiz Perdón, leí mal las condiciones. Ya modifiqué la consulta para agrupar las condiciones de manera correcta.